# Detect line wrap in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, linefeed, word-wrap

I am making a program that involves saving text entered in a `JTextArea` saved to a file. The problem is, when I use `setWrapStyleWord()`, line feeds are not created when the text wraps to a new line. Therefore, the text printed to the file is in one really long line.

Is there any way to detect when a line wraps so that I can insert a line feed, or is there a way to simply add line feeds wherever a line wrap occurs?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. If it wraps ... there's no newline; it's a single line of text. A different sized JTextArea would wrap the lines differently, which is the whole point. You're basically asking how to set an arbitrary line length in your file based on the width of your JTextArea.

Comment: That is what occurred to me. It's why I wasn't so sure it was possible, but I think that just scanning the text for whitespace and adding a line feed every 5 occurrences or so would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Use `javax.swing.text.Utilities`

```
public static final int getRowStart(JTextComponent c, int offs)
public static final int getRowEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs)
```

pass you `JTextArea` and offset of previous line

Answer (score 2):

This context sensitive.  That is, depending on the size of the `JTextArea`, the word break will change, as BrianRoach has already stated.

If, however, you are really determined, you might be able to figure it about by using the `LineBreakMeasurer`.

Check out this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you were wrapping on characters instead of words, you could:

If you are using a monospace font in the `JTextArea`, you could process the string afterwards to add a `\n` after every `x` number of characters, where `x` is the number of characters that fill up a line in your text area.

Applying this idea to word wrapping would involve just looping through your string and, as suggested in the comments to this answer, add the line break so that it occurs on whitespace.

Comment: Except he's using word wrap ... which means he'd need to duplicate the logic that breaks on the whitespace based on the width.

Comment: @BrianRoach Good point- I read that and apparently forgot right away.

Comment: To be fair, it's not rocket science - he'd just need to go to index `i` as you say, then backtrack until he hit whitespace. Rinse, repeat. The font sizing stuff is still going to be wonky though if it's a proportional font given how `getColumns()` works.

Comment: @BrianRoach I was editing my answer to say that while you were writing that comment. I'm wondering if there are any more things that need to be considered, but I haven't thought of any...

Comment: Of course, the problem remains that this only works for monospaced fonts.

Comment: I have been thinking that I just scan the string for whitespace, and after every 5 occurrences or so, I would add a \n. It wouldn't exactly resemble the text area, but I think it's good enough.